# Can't change attributes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a form on HTML and I want to be able to change the attributes of a div and a button but I can't make it work

```
<form>
<button type='button' id='other'>Sub</button>
<select id="prop">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opci&oacute;n</option>
    <option value="1">".Otro."</option>;</select>
<button type='button' id='btn'>Votar</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id='one'>
    <input type='text' name='producto' placeholder='Producto'>
    <input type='text' name='precio' placeholder='Precio'></div>
```

And my Javascript is

```
var gone = document.getElementById('btn');
var div1 = document.getElementById('one');
var opc = document.getElementById("prop");
var btn = document.getElementById('other');
gone.addEventListener('click', function () {
if (opc.value == "1") {
    div1.style.color = "red";
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
}});
```

I don't see how it's wrong. Thanks for your help!
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y1LbfyL/11/)

Edit: I posted the wrong code and the wrong link, this is my current code, sorry about the mess.

Comment: what's `btn` in this line `btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');` here ??

Comment: In your jsfiddle the visibility of div1 is set to hidden but not here?

Comment: you just want to change color of div when selecting Otro from drop down this is only you want to do??

Comment: you should use backgroundcolor for the div..if u want to change the color for the input than use class="one" on the input and than set the style to color

Comment: already changed it to "background-color" and still nothing

Comment: its not background-color...it is backgroundColor

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your question, not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `opc.value==1`

you've done

```
div1.style.color = "red";
btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
```

but your code trigger the submit of the form. so the page reload.

Comment: it doesn't work even if I delete the setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

You must add `e.preventDefault()` to your handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/0y1LbfyL/10/

You may want to change div `one`'s background rather than color?

**AFTER YOUR UPDATE**

Changed my answer to :

http://jsfiddle.net/0y1LbfyL/11/

Comment: I changed it to background-color and it still doesn't work

Comment: div1.style.backgroundColor this works...check your character case ..but i think u wish to set the background color for the input box .In that case you should set the class = one" on the input and set their color to red

Comment: Did you look at my code?

Comment: @SergioYáñezJiménez see edit please.

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you very much, it worked for the visibility, but apparently my error was not spelling it as "backgroundColor". Still, it was very helpful.

Comment: @px5x2 it works now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @px5x2 Also, I would never have guessed the preventDefault function was needed

Comment: @SergioYáñezJiménez yw you can accept the answer then.